# Re-size circle using paperJS

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to re-size a circle using papeJS but since i used two `onMouseDrag` function it if conflicting. I am unable to create it. Can anyone help me. [Here is the fiddle with circle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbKRN/2/)

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
        var raster = new Raster({
            source: 'Chrysanthemum.jpg',
            position: view.center
        });
        var path = null;
        var circles = [];
        var isDrawing = false;
        var draggingIndex = -1;
        var segment, movePath;
        var resize = false;
        project.activeLayer.selected = false;
        function onMouseDrag(event) {
            if (!isDrawing && circles.length > 0) {
                for (var ix = 0; ix < circles.length; ix++) {
                    if (circles[ix].contains(event.point)) {
                        draggingIndex = ix;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (draggingIndex > -1) {
                circles[draggingIndex].position = event.point;
            } else {
                path = new Path.Circle({
                    center: event.point,
                    radius: (event.downPoint - event.point).length,
                    fillColor: null,
                    strokeColor: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 10
                });

                path.removeOnDrag();
                isDrawing = true;
            }
        }
        ;

        function onMouseUp(event) {
            if (isDrawing) {
                circles.push(path);
            }
            isDrawing = false;
            draggingIndex = -1;
        }
        ;

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            project.activeLayer.selected = false;
            if (event.item)
                event.item.selected = true;
            resize = true;
        }

        var segment, path;
        var movePath = false;
        function onMouseDown(event) {
            segment = path = null;
            var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
            if (!hitResult)
                return;

            if (hitResult) {
                path = hitResult.item;
                if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
                    segment = hitResult.segment;
                } else if (hitResult.type == 'stroke') {
                    var location = hitResult.location;
                    segment = path.insert(location.index + 1, event.point);
                    path.smooth();
                }
            }
            movePath = hitResult.type == 'fill';
            if (movePath)
                project.activeLayer.addChild(hitResult.item);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I would make people use an additional key on the keyboard if they want to resize. Say `Shift` or `Ctrl` or something, you can never know what the user actually wants to do. This would also, incidentally, make your coding easier.

Comment: Without any key event i re-sized a circle. But the issue is circle path is re-sized the whole circle. Can you help.

Answer (score 3):

First, your code (on jsfiddle) does not run.

1. The paperjs external resource returned a 404. https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js works for paperjs.
2. The raster source was for a local file, not a URI.
3. In onMouseDown, `project.hitTest` references an undefined `hitOptions`.

It seems from your question that you want to be able to drag the circle segments to resize the circle, and you tried using two `onMouseDrag` functions to do that, which would not work.  Instead, both operations should be in the same `onMouseDrag`, using if-then-else to choose between them.  To make this work as expected, the item that was hit should be stored in `onMouseDown` instead of whatever circle your code finds at the beginning of `onMouseDrag`.  For example, here `onMouseDrag` can either "move" or "resize" ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JyREr/3/)):

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
    var raster = new Raster({
        source: 'http://i140.photobucket.com/albums/r10/Array39/Chrysanthemum.jpg',
        position: view.center
    });
    var circles = [];
    var hitItem = null;
    var currentAction = null;

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        project.activeLayer.selected = false;
        if (event.item) {
            event.item.selected = true;
        }
    }

    function onMouseDown(event) {
        hitItem = null;
        var aColor = new Color('black');
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            circles[i].fillColor = aColor;
        }
        view.draw();
        var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point);
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            circles[i].fillColor = null;
        }
        view.draw();
        if (!hitResult) {
            return; //only happens if we don't even hit the raster
        }
        hitItem = hitResult.item;
        if (circles.indexOf(hitItem) < 0) {
            var newCircle = new Path.Circle({
                center: event.point,
                radius: 2,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 10
            });
            hitItem = newCircle;
            circles.push(hitItem);
            currentAction = 'resize';
            return;
        }
        if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
            currentAction = 'resize';
        } else if (hitResult.type == 'stroke') {
            hitItem.insert(hitResult.location.index + 1, event.point);
            hitItem.smooth();
            currentAction = 'resize';
        } else if (hitResult.type == 'fill') {
            currentAction = 'move';
        }
    }

    function onMouseDrag(event) {
        if (!hitItem) {
            return;
        }
        if (currentAction == 'move') {
            hitItem.position = event.point;
        } else if (currentAction == 'resize') {
            if ((event.downPoint - event.point).length >= 1) {
            hitItem.fitBounds(new Rectangle(event.downPoint, event.point), true);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Also note:

1. In `onMouseDown`, the function returns if `!hitResult`, so you do not need to test `if (hitResult)` right after that `return`.
2. Naming variables the same as objects makes searching more difficult, e.g., in your code `path` is an instance of `Path`.
3. Using the same variable for different purposes makes code more difficult to parse, e.g., in your code `path` is used to create new circles as well as to store which circle has been selected.
4. You have multiple variables defined twice: `path`, `movePath`, and `segment`.
5. If a variable will only be used in a single function, e.g., `movePath` and `segment`, then it makes the code more readable if the variable is defined in that function.  Also, `movePath` is only used in a single if-statement, which just adds items back to the layer, but the only items not in the layer have been removed when the circle was originally drawn.  Since those items cannot be hit, the item that was hit must already be in the layer.
6. The variable `segment` is not used.
7. It makes the code flow/read better if the functions are ordered logically.  In this case, `onMouseMove` should go first because it happens before the button is clicked.  Then `onMouseDown` goes next because it must happen before the other actions.  Then `onMouseDrag`, and finally `onMouseUp`.
8. Instead of creating new circles in `onMouseDrag` and then throwing them away on the next drag, it makes more sense to create one in `onMouseDown` if there was no item hit, or if the hit item is not a circle.  Then in `onMouseDown`, you just resize that circle.  `Path.scale` or `Path.fitBounds` can be used for such resizing.
9. Instead of using multiple boolean variables to keep track of the current action (e.g., resize vs move), it is more logical to have a single variable keeping track of the current action.
10. Instead of your code to find whether the point is within a circle, the code I am using temporarily sets the circles' `fillColor`, do the hitTest, and then clears the circles' `fillColor`.  I did this because when you hit a stroke, the shape of the circle changes, for which your code to find the `draggingIndex` does not account.